# application executor vs lpszUserName of ADsOpenObject

Tags: c++, active-directory, adsi

I would like to understand application executor and lpszUserName of ADsOpenObject.

I can't understand why my program ignores lpszUserName's domain, while connect to application executor's domain.

Here is my code.

```cpp
CComPtr<IADs> iad;
ADsOpenObject("LDAP://RootDSE", "test2.com\tester", "pw", ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, IID_IADs, (void **)&iad);

VARIANT dc;
VariantInit(&dc);
iad->Get(CComBSTR("defaultNamingContext"), &dc);
```

And this is a scenario.

Application executor(test1.com\tester) executes the program that calls ADsOpenObject hard coded "test2.com\tester" at application server(test3.com\testServer).

- application executor : test1.com\tester
- lpszUserName : test2.com\tester
- application server : test3.com\testServer
- All domains trust each other.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It does not ignore the domain name in the `lpszUserName` parameter, it just does not use it to decide on which domain to connect to.

The `lpszPathName` parameter decides which domain to connect to, and uses the credentials in `lpszUserName` (which could be credentials from a different, trusted domain).

If you do not include a domain name in `lpszPathName`, then it will connect to the domain of the current user, not the domain of the credentials you pass (if they're different). If you want to specify a different domain, then you will need to include the domain name in the path, like this:

```
"LDAP://test2.com/RootDSE"
```

You can use a specific domain controller there, if you want to. More details about how to construct the path is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/adsi/ldap-adspath).

Comment: Thank u so much. But I'm not clear..

I didn't include a domain name in lpszPathName. That means target domain will be test3.com that application server joined to and test2.com authenticates lpszUserName(test2.com\tester).
In this case,  ADsOpenObject isn't influenced by application executor(test1.com\tester)?

Comment: Sorry, I just tested this. It uses the domain of the executor, not the domain of the computer.